# XEN Server VM Creation Error

Tags: virtualization, xen, citrix

Has anyone seen this before and this recently started occurring when a VM boots.

> 4/7/2011 11:53:08 AM Error: Starting VM 'Web Server 1' - INVALID_SOURCE - Unable to access a required file in the specified repository: file:///tmp/cdrom-repo-q0Mzmz/isolinux/vmlinuz.

I can't seem to fix this issue. Thoughts?

Thank for any help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue once, and it turns out I put the wrong Centos CD. It needs Centos Install DVD or CD1, not Live CD. Alternatively, you can do network install from Centos Vault: http://vault.centos.org/5.4/os/i386/

Answer (score 0):

It appears that a CDROM that was acessible at /tmp/ is not acessible anymore. Maybe you unmounted or removed it some way?